# twitter api v. 1.1 search query not working using C# wrapper (twitterizer)

Tags: c#, twitter

I am modifying twitterizer version 1.0 to be compatible with recent twitter api v. 1.1.

while modifying and testing I got stuck with twitter api 1.1 search

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json
```

I am using twitterizer v. 1.0.

Has anybody successfully called the above url and got json back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To inform whoever wondering, next version of Twitterizer (2 or 3) seems moving away from 1 in dealing with JSON.

They now use Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late to answer but there is a good remake of Twitterizer for Twitter API 1.1 at this link:

[Twitterizer-Remaked For API 1.1](https://bitbucket.org/szrsharp/twitterizer-remaked-for-api-1.1/overview)

The only problem is that the documentation of the remake is in japanese. Use Google translator.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @backslash17 doesn't seem to be working anymore: the japanese dll mod seems to be idle aswell.

Since I had the same problem (using Twitterizer in an old .NET 3.5 application) I switched to TweetSharp, which AFAIK is the only library available for .NET 3.5 (and also 2.0) with Twitter API 1.1 support.

For further information you can [read my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27449299/1233379).

I can personally guarantee that it works because I used it in an old 3.5 project and I managed to make it work (in fact it saved my day).