# Twitter Api 1.1. with .net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, api, twitter

I am using .net 3.5 framework. I can not access my twitter account from my website since the twitter's api was changed. I have searched other alternative referances for my project that supports Api 1.1. But no way, always told me "You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or 
content files that are compatible with that framework."

Can anyone please tell me some other dlls compatible with both twitter's Api 1.1 and .net framework 3.5 so that I can access again to my twitter account from my website?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TweetSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TweetSharp/) v2.3.1. It supports Twitter API 1.1 and it also provides full .NET Framework 3.5 (and also 2.0) support.

You can get it via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TweetSharp/) or [GitHub](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp): if you use NuGet Package Manager, you can just install it from the Command Window by doing that:

```
Install-Package TweetSharp
```

I can personally guarantee that it works because I used it in an old 3.5 project and I managed to make it work.

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: if your project doesn't include Newtonsoft Json.NET >= 5.0.6 (which is a required dependance) NuGet will automatically try to get an updated version which could give you .NET 3.5 compatibility issues. If you run into this issue, just [download Json.NET v5.0.6 manually](https://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/107620), delete all the stuff downloaded by NuGet (including the .refresh file) and replace them with the Json.NET dll files you downloaded (those in the /Net35/ folder).